# HTML table caption as part of header row

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table header row that includes a title on the left as well as "Sample header" on the right.  For accessibility and to be semantically correct, the title should probably be in a `<caption>` tag, but "Sample header" isn't part of the title so it probably shouldn't be inside of `<caption>`.  The caption can't be inside the row since it has to be the first element after `<table>`.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<table>
    <caption>Caption</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr class="sample">
            <th colspan="2">Sample header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The caption ends up as a separate line above the table, while I would like it to be on the same line as "Sample header".

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:  http://jsfiddle.net/vueLL5ce/5/.  It sets 'caption`'s position to relative and manually moves it where I want.  The two main problems with this approach is that repositioning the caption still leaves its original space above the table and I'm working with pixels which vary between browsers so it won't necessarily line up correctly.

Is there a good way of achieving this?  Am I stuck with including the header info inside of `<caption>` (and styling to look like a table row) or creating a regular table row and not using `<caption>`?

Comment: Include relevant code in the question itself, explain what you have tried, and exactly how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a cross-browser solution.  The key is to set `line-height: 0` (plain 0 doesn't work in IE6, but I don't need to support it).  Firefox also wouldn't let me reposition the caption directly, so I had to add another `span`.  I still don't like dealing with pixels directly, so any suggestions on that end would be great.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vueLL5ce/8/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <caption><span>Caption</span></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr class="captionRow">
                <th colspan="2">Sample header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data1</td>
                <td>Data2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: #FFFFDD;
}

table {
    border: solid 1px Black;
    width: 100%;
}

table caption {
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

table caption span {
    position: relative;
    left: 4px;
    top: 14px;
}

table th {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.captionRow th {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move background color from div to table and it should remove the color from the top for you. see attached fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vueLL5ce/4/)

```
table {
border: solid 1px Black;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFDD;
```

}

I would remove the caption, use the column head and separate the two items with there own class then align them in your css. Updated the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vueLL5ce/3/) This way you don't have the spacing issue at all.

Comment: The color was just to show the extra spacing, which I would like to get rid of since the text is no longer there, and you still have the absolute positioning issue.  Also, I think your link is incorrect since it goes back to my version.

Comment: Apologies i didn't noticed the link was wrong sorry. you could just use two separate div tags in the table header and align them left and right and then you would not need to use the caption.

Comment: I have updated the answer, i am not sure if this is what your after or not though. However this does solve the extra spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and update.  I alluded to your solution with `Am I stuck with ... creating a regular table row and not using <caption>?`

Comment: Thank you i am glad i could help, i tired to think of a solution to removed the space created from the caption but i had no luck either.

Comment: I tried relative position for the table with negative top, but then you're stuck with the space at the bottom.  :)  `<caption>` also has to be the next element immediately after `<table>` so it's can't be inside the row.  It seems like accessibility and a specific UI design are not compatible in this case.